# Is it possible for a vertex attribute to be an array in GLSL-ES 2.0?

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

In GLSL-ES it's possible to have arrays. For example, the [GLSL ES Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) gives the following example of a uniform variable that's an array:

```
uniform vec4 lightPosition[4];
```

Is it possible to have vertex attributes that are arrays? In other words, is the following legal according to the spec?

```
attribute vec4 foo[3];  // three vec4s per vertex
```

Is the answer (either yes or no) explicitly mentioned anywhere in the GLSL ES Specification? (I can't find it, but I haven't read every line of the spec.)

Also, if it is legal, how does one initialize such an attribute using the OpenGL ES 2.0 API? (Assuming `glVertexAttribPointer` would be used, what is the layout of the vertices/array-elements/vector-elements?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [GLSL ES 2.0 specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) states that attributes cannot be declared as arrays.

In desktop GL, you can have attribute arrays. When the attribute is assigned an attribute index (either with `glBindAttribLocation` or automatically by the shader being linked), it will get consecutive attributes, starting with the one you requested if you used `glBindAttribLocation`. So if `foo` was given the location 5, `foo[0]` would be 5, `foo[1]` would be 6, and `foo[2]` would be 7.

If there is some ES 2.0 extension to allow attribute arrays, it would likely work like this.

Comment: Where does the specification say that they cannot be declared as arrays?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: Section 4.3.3, entitled surprisingly enough, "Attribute". It's the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: @NicolBolas; On the desktop it became legal to use array attributes in version 1.5 (GL 3.2), so it's fairly new there as well.