# GLSL per vertex fixed size array

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

Is it possible in desktop GLSL to pass a fixed size array of floats to the vertex shader as an attribute? If yes, how?

I want to have per vertex weights for character animation so I would like to have something like the following in my vertex shader:

```
attribute float weights[25];
```

How would I fill the attribute array from my C++ & OpenGL program? I have seen in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220484/is-it-possible-for-a-vertex-attribute-to-be-an-array-in-glsl-es-2-0) that I could get the attribute location of the array attribute and then just add the index to that location. Could someone give an example on that for my pretty large array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's start with what you asked for.

On pretty much no hardware that exists currently will `attribute float weights[25];` compile. While shaders can have arrays of attributes, each array index represents a *new* attribute index. And on all hardware the currently exists, the maximum number of attribute indices is... 16. You'd need 25, and that's *just* for the weights.

Now, you can mitigate this easily enough by remembering that you can use `vec4` attributes. Thus, you store every four array elements in a single attribute. Your array would be `attribute vec4 weights[7];` which is doable. Your weight-fetching logic will have to change of course.

Even so, you don't seem to be taking in the ramifications of what this would actually *mean* for your vertex data. Each attribute represents a component of a vertex's data. Each vertex for a rendering call will have the same amount of data; the contents of that data will differ, but not how much data.

In order to do what you're suggesting, every *vertex* in your mesh would need 25 floats describing the weight. Even if this was stored as normalized unsigned bytes, that's still 25 extra bytes worth of data at a minimum. That's a lot. Especially considering that for the *vast* majority of vertices, most of these values will be 0. Even in the worst case, you'd be looking at maybe 6-7 bones affecting an single vertex.

The way skinning is generally done in vertex shaders is to limit the number of bones that affects a single vertex to *four*. This way, you don't use an array of attributes; you just use a `vec4` attribute for the weights. Of course, you also now need to say which bone is associated with which weight. So you have a second `vec4` attribute that specifies the bone index for that weight.

This strikes a good balance. You only take up 2 extra attributes (which can be unsigned bytes in terms of size). And for the vast majority of vertices, you'll never even notice, because most vertices are only influenced by 1-3 bones. A few uses 4, and fewer still use 5+. In those cases, you just cut off the lowest weights and recompute the weights of the others proportionately.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answered all my questions and even more! I hope this will greatly improve the performance! Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

Nicol Bolas already gave you an answer how to restructure your task. You should do it, because processing 25 floats for a vertex, probably through some quaternion multiplication will waste a lot of good GPU processing power; most of the attributes for a vertex will translate close to an identity transform anyway.

However for academic reasons I'm going to tell you, how to pass 25 floats per vertex. The key is not using attributes for this, but fetching the data from some buffer, a texture. The GLSL vertex shader stage has the builtin variable `gl_VertexID`, which passes the index of the currently processed vertex. With recent OpenGL you can access textures from the vertex shader as well. So you have a texture of size `vertex_count × 25` holding the values. In your vertex shader you can access them using the `texelFetch` function, i.e. `texelFetch(param_buffer, vec2(gl_VertexID, 3));`

If used in skeletal animation this system is often referred to as *texture skinning*. However it should be used sparingly, as it's a real performance hog. But sometimes you can't avoid it, for example when implementing a facial animation system where you have to weight all the vertices to 26 muscles, if you want to accurately simulate a human face.